# Preview Score from MIDI file in python

Tags: python, midi

I would like to be able to get png of a score from a MIDI file from within a python program.

Separately, I know MuseScore is able to open MIDI files and convert them into a score, so this should theoretically be possible.

My current solution is to just use the lilypond functions !midi2ly and !lilypond -fpng, but midi2ly struggles a bit with the midis I use due to the number of voices present.

```
!midi2ly "sample from g.midi"
!lilypond -fpng "sample from g-midi.ly"
```

Here is the ideal output (from MuseScore) and lilypond's attempt output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ0zL.jpg

Comment: could you post your current solution?

Comment: I have edited question to include my current solution and output

Comment: Does MuseScore generate that file directly from the midi file? That's impressive to get the key signature and time signature correct!   There are probably multiple parameters for lilypond to preset the quantization of  notes and key signature and voices to attempt to make a better approximation of the score.  But you know, going from score to midi is simple and accurate.  Going from midi to score includes a lot of guesswork.

Comment: MuseScore generated that file from the same MIDI!

Answer (score 1):

Try music21!

```
import music21
parsed = music21.converter.parse('source.mid')
parsed.show('musicxml.png')
```

Use `.write()` rather than `.show()` if you don't want to launch a viewer.